# I was laying in bed or lying in bed?

Tags: word-choice, lie-lay-lain-laid

I was laying in bed or lying in bed?

Comment: It would be "I was lying in bed." But for simple past you would use "I lay in bed."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Google NGrams, "lying in bed" is much more common.

"To lay" is a transitive verb. It can be reflexive - "I lay myself", "I am laying myself", "I was laying myself" - but it requires an object noun.

"To lie" by contrast is intransitive. It is an indicator of state, not action. Thus, your statement, which indicates your state in the past perfect, should use this verb and not "lay".

If "I was laying in bed", the connotation is that I was in the act of laying *something* in that bed, and the sentence is not proper unless that object is either stated explicitly or inferred by context; it can range from the innocent reflexive ("I was laying myself in bed") to the innocent transitive ("I was laying my infant daughter in bed") to the sexual ("I was laying my girlfriend in bed") to the absurd ("I was laying eggs in bed").

Comment: To add to this, *laying* for *lying* is dialectal and locally valid (certainly round here in Sussex, England) but definitely non-standard.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but, even though I am a fond of NGrams, I think they are a better guide to usage than grammar.

Comment: There is much to be said for "correct by common usage". It's how languages evolve. Otherwise, we'd still be speaking Anglo-Saxon (if that).

Answer (score 9):

"I was lying in bed" is correct unless, of course, like a chicken you were laying an egg!

Answer (score 3):

You are most probably lying in bed.

Unless you are a hen and you are laying eggs in someone's bed, that is.